# Trying to update a table using a trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

When the 'rsform_submission_values' table has an entry with certain critera in two colomns, I need to Insert a row in a table called 'user_usergroup_map'.  To add a row to 'user_usergroup_map' I need to lookup the UserId in a table called 'ch54b_rsform_submission' as the userID isn't stored in
'rsform_submission_values'.  The common field to link two tables is the SubmissionId field.

I have been looking at a trigger to acheive this, however, it doesn't write anything to the 'user_usergroup_map' table.

Is there something obvious wrong with the mysql below?   Or is there a way to troubleshoot a trigger in MYSQL so I can see if any issues.

thank you Pete.

```
IF NEW.FieldName = '_STATUS' AND NEW.FieldValue = '1' THEN
        INSERT INTO ch54b_user_usergroup_map (`user_id`, `group_id`) 
        SELECT UserId, '12' 
        FROM ch54b_rsform_submission_values 
        INNER JOIN ch54b_rsform_submission ON ch54b_rsform_submission_values.SubmissionId = ch54b_rsform_submissions.SubmissionId;
    END IF
```

I have been looking at a trigger to acheive this, however, it doesn't write anything to the 'user_usergroup_map' table.

Comment: *Is there something obvious wrong with the mysql below?* Of course. 1) This is a part of the code whereas you must provide complete trigger code. 2) Your SELECT does not contain any condition which restricts the output to the data which is related to current row (NEW values), so you insert all paired values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to be attempting to insert all users into user_usergroup_map, rather than the one related to the row being inserted/updated.  Therefore I suggest something simpler:

```sql
IF NEW.FieldName = '_STATUS' AND NEW.FieldValue = '1' THEN
    INSERT INTO ch54b_user_usergroup_map (`user_id`, `group_id`) 
    SELECT UserId, 12
    FROM ch54b_rsform_submission
    WHERE SubmissionId = NEW.SubmissionId;
END IF
```

NB if you have a unique key on user_usergroup_map (user_id, group_id) and you want to handle the case where the user is already in that group, then you could change `INSERT` to `INSERT IGNORE` to avoid an error

Comment: Thank you Rob - a much simpler way than my attempt!  It still doesn't work when a new row is inserted....    There are other rows inserted at the same time using the same SubmissionID (just different FieldName and FieldValue).  Would that cause confusion to the Where statement?

Comment: Got it working using your code, but had to change the IF to pick another entry.  Not sure why it didn't work before.  Thank you for your help.